# Open georeferenced Raster .PNG .TAB in QGIS

Tags: raster, coordinate-systems, qgis

how can I open a raster file in .png and .tab (made with MapInfo) and keep the georeferenced form in QGIS.
thanks a lot

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: Flagged so that the question is migrated to GIS

Answer (score 0):

You can use Georeferencer tools, but you must activate first in plugins.

[image]